# How can I prevent \ from being added from the form input?

Tags: php, html, forms

The html form accepts textarea input, and I am using $_POST value to put the input value to textarea when I am displaying it. 
For example.

```
<html>
<?php if($_POST['input'){
<form method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">
<textarea name="input" cols="60" rows="20"><?=$_POST['input']?></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Test it">
</form>
<?php
} else {
?>
Please copy in a text of your choice
<br /><br />
<form method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">
<textarea name="input" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Test it">
</form>
</html>
```

Everything works fine except that backslash '\' is added to every single quote, and double quotes. 
How can I set some setting to prevent backslash from being added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable magic quotes - see http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php - if you're on shared hosting and your hoster is stupid and doesn't want to / let you change it (see that page for why it is stupid), use `stripslashes()` on every value you get out ouf the `$_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE` arrays.

On a side note, don't echo input values back (that includes `PHP_SELF`) into the HTML output without sending them through `htmlspecialchars()`, or you have security issues. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting for more information.

Comment: but be careful! those backslashes are there to prevent sql-injections - not the best way, but the php way...

Comment: Exactly. In ADDITION use `<?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['input'])?>` instead of `<?=$_POST['input']?>`. Otherwise you may get unexpected results (such es invalid html as output) or this could even be used for malicious intentions (XSS).

Comment: No, "the PHP way" is to use `mysqli_real_escape_string` or prepared statements or whatever the database connector offers - magic quotes are always a mistake.

Comment: you are right - that's the "good" php way. But I get the impression that most hoster configure the magic quotes in order to help beginners not to make too big mistakes - that's why you find those magic quotes often in php environments and nowhere else :-)

Answer (score 2):

After a long search I solved this problem like this:

In your page where you want to display the textarea content, just add this

```
< ? php echo stripslashes($shortcode_name) ? >
```

Of course you need to replace `$shortcode_name` with your shortcode.
That is all.
SOLVED

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

```
<textarea name="input" cols="60" rows="20"><?php echo stripslashes($_POST['input']); ?></textarea>
```