# How do I prevent the hotkey ` from being added to a html form input?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, hotkeys

I used [the instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2511474/2842962) to turn ` into a shortcut thusly:

```
function reset_shortcut_key(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 192) reset_data();
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', reset_shortcut_key, false);
```

It loads the next problem successfully, but when I hit this hotkey while focused on a `<form> <input> </form>` environment, the ` character momentarily shows up (before the next problem is loaded).

> [image: A fill-in-the-gaps puzzle with a ` character showing.]

I want to prevent it from showing the ` character.

**Question**: How do I prevent the hotkey ` from being added to a form input?

Other related questions are [How can I prevent \ from being added from the form input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924864/how-can-i-prevent-from-being-added-from-the-form-input) (but this is about stripping slashes) and [Javascript -> Hotkeys -> Disable for input fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024748/javascript-hotkeys-disable-for-input-fields) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50663339/how-to-disable-hotkeys-when-inputting)) (but I want the hotkey to work).

---

*Edit*: Judging from the current comment and answer, the appropriate function is `event.preventDefault()`.  I'm still not clear on how to actually implement this.

Simply adding it before or after `document.addEventListener('keyup', reset_shortcut_key, false);` doesn't do anything.  Beyond this,

```
        document.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           reset_shortcut_key();
       }, false);
```

and

```
        document.querySelector("#input-guess").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           reset_shortcut_key();
       }, false);
```

(where `id="input-guess"` is the name of my `<input>`) both prevent `reset_shortcut_key()` from being called.  Modifying `reset_shortcut_key` as follows doesn't change anything:

```
        function reset_shortcut_key(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(e.keyCode == 192) reset_data();
        }
```

At this point, I'm just making guesses on what to do.

Comment: prevent default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was a second issue: I needed to use `keydown` (instead of `keyup`).  After making that change, the following code (utilizing `preventDefault()`) works:

```
function reset_shortcut_key(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 192) {
    e.preventDefault();
    reset_data();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

```
event.preventDefault();
```